# Change Host OS in Python-generated ZIP file

Tags: python

For reasons unknown, Amazon's Lambda service requires that permissions for native libraries need to be set in the ZIP file we upload. This isn't easy from within Windows.

I found some Python code, and adapted it to set the 764 permissions I needed:

```
import zipfile
import os

srcFileName = os.getcwd() + '\\bin\\Release\\netcoreapp1.0\\input.zip'
tmpFileName = os.getcwd() + '\\bin\\Release\\netcoreapp1.0\\publish.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(srcFileName, 'r') as sz:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(tmpFileName, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as z:
        for name in sz.namelist():
            srcFile = sz.open(name, "r")
            print(name)
            zi = zipfile.ZipInfo(name)
            zi.external_attr = (0o764 << 16)
            z.writestr(zi, sz.read(name))
        z.close()
        sz.close()
```

But then I hit problem number two: ZIP files store the Host OS that the file was added to the archive on (specification here: http://www.fileformat.info/format/zip/corion.htm)

Setting the permission alone does not get accepted by Amazon. If I hex edit the zip file and change the OS from Windows to Unix, the permissions are then accepted by Amazon.

Is there any way I can programatically set the host OS using the Python zip functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm an idiot. RTFM is definitely needed here.

I found `zi.create_system = 3` can be applied to change the host OS to unix:

import zipfile
    import os

```
srcFileName = os.getcwd() + '\\bin\\Release\\netcoreapp1.0\\input.zip'
tmpFileName = os.getcwd() + '\\bin\\Release\\netcoreapp1.0\\publish.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(srcFileName, 'r') as sz:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(tmpFileName, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as z:
        for name in sz.namelist():
            srcFile = sz.open(name, "r")
            print(name)
            zi = zipfile.ZipInfo(name)
            zi.create_system = 3
            zi.external_attr = (0o764 << 16)
            z.writestr(zi, sz.read(name))
        z.close()
        sz.close()
```